# Spark: Mongo-Hadoop how to query

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, mongodb-hadoop

I am trying to do a $near query with MongoDB using Spark and mongo-hadoop with lat/lon coordinates that change. How can I do a query with mongo-hadoop?

Apart from somethnig like:

`mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.query", "{'field':'value'}")` I cannot see anything with sense.

any idea?

Comment: Last time I've checked this was the only public option and didn't work particularly well. Also it has to be strict JSON.

Comment: Yes I am getting the impression that using MongoDB with Spark it is a sort of disaster. The ideal will be working for geoqueries in memory creating geohash indexes etc. I tried using lucene/spatial4j in memory which gave me the exact results of mongodb but it was way far slower than Mongoldb. Anyway running millions query in memory maybe Mongodb won't scale that well and Lucene solution would win. Another thing I tried is creating a QuadTree with ESRI always in memory but I have no time to test the quality of the results at the moment.

Comment: [Magellan](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan)?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why the use of `mongo.input.query` is not suitable for you ? i.e. you could substitute the lat/long as variables in the string pull.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can see the `com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil`, there are lots of config query settings:

```
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.query","{key:{\"$eq\":20160517080039}}");
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.fields","{key:0}");
mongodbConfig.setInt("mongo.input.limit", 1);
```

Comment: Use Proper Formatting